# Visual Studio can't find Text Box

Tags: authentication, error-handling, textbox

Creating a Scheduling system in my Senior Project, Teacher couldn't find out why it's not finding either.
EmployeeIDTxtBox and PasswordTxtBox are both Text Boxes but cannot be found.

Thanks for the help!

Can anyone find the error?

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;
using System.Data.SqlClient;
using System.Data;

public partial class LogIn : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }

    protected void SubmitBtn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection("Data Source=MISSQL;Initial Catalog=NUSSOFTDB;Integrated Security=True");
        con.Open();
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("Select * FROM EmployeeT WHERE EmployeeID='" + Convert.ToInt16(EmployeeIDTxtBox.Text) + "' and Password ='" + PasswordTxtBox.Text + "'", con);
        SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
        DataTable dt = new DataTable();
        da.Fill(dt);
        if (dt.Rows.Count > 0)
        {
            Response.Redirect("Schedule1.aspx");
        }
        else
        {
            Response.Write("<script>alert('Please enter valid Username and Password')</script>");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I don't see `EmployeeIDTxtBox` or `PasswordTxtBox` defined anywhere. Is there some more code you haven't posted?

Comment: I'm guessing it is a scope issue which is probably what @Will was referring to.  Note, you are using the textboxes in  `Class LogIn : System.Web.UI.Page`  Are they declared in and instantiated in the same scope?

Comment: Sorry guys, yes its in the design page. I figured it out I was calling employeeID from the EmployeeT table when it was actually re-labeled EmailAddress. All is well thanks for the responses!